# Javascript sorting array into a tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

So let's say that I have an array, and it contains 10 elements. I want to set the first element as the root, and then if the next number is smaller, put it to the left, if larger to the right. How would I do this?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: To the left, or right of what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I have figured it out now. I can just set another type called tree and it has itself, leftbranch and rightbranch, and leftbranch and rightbranch are also trees.